# How to automatically Scroll a text window on loading it

Tags: javascript, html, text, scroll

I have a html text box with scroll. Is it possible to get the box to scroll to a certain point on loading ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use scrollTop

```
document.getElementById('your_div_id').scrollTop = 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use an id on a certain point in the text:

```
<span id='scrollTo'>lorem ipsum...</span>
```

and then in the URL:

`localhost/index.html#scrollTo`

or:

if you want to go the javascript route you can use the jquery $.scroll method